# Type error before replacement rule is applied

Tags: replacement, data-types

When I type

```
a <> "0" /. {a -> "1"}
```

I get the error

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in a<>0. >>
```

Followed by the answer I want

```
"10"
```

What should I do instead so that I don't get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the following

```
a <> "0" /. {a -> "1"} // Quiet
```

or

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[a <> "0"] /. {a -> "1"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a lazier StringJoin:

```
stritch[a_String, b_String] := a <> b
stritch[a, "0"] /. a -> "1"
(* 10 *)
```